# Trying to call SAbre Soap API FareLLSRQ IN soapui, nad get an error "<stl:Message code="7012">MDR SUBSET DOES NOT EXIST</stl:Message>"

Tags: sabre

After creating a session SessionCreateRQ in SOAPUI, I am calling this service

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"       xmlns:sec="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:mes="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:ns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10">
       <soapenv:Header>
          <sec:Security>
             <sec:BinarySecurityToken>
      Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/CERTG!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3296706632225343066!980366!0
         </sec:BinarySecurityToken>
      </sec:Security>
      <mes:MessageHeader mes:id="1" mes:version="2.0">
         <mes:From>
            <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
            <mes:PartyId mes:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">999999</mes:PartyId>
         </mes:From>
         <mes:To>
            <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
            <mes:PartyId mes:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">123123</mes:PartyId>
         </mes:To>
         <mes:CPAId>OD</mes:CPAId>
         <mes:ConversationId>UB11</mes:ConversationId>
         <mes:Service mes:type="OTA">FareLLSRQ</mes:Service>
         <mes:Action>FareLLSRQ</mes:Action>
         <mes:MessageData>
            <mes:MessageId>1340037420096900611</mes:MessageId>
            <mes:Timestamp>2017-03-17T11:40:19</mes:Timestamp>
            <!--Optional:-->
         </mes:MessageData>
      </mes:MessageHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:FareRQ ReturnHostCommand="true" Version="2.6.0">
         <ns:OptionalQualifiers>
        <ns:TimeQualifiers>
            <ns:TravelDateOptions Start="02-17" />
        </ns:TimeQualifiers>
    </ns:OptionalQualifiers>
    <ns:OriginDestinationInformation>
        <ns:FlightSegment>
            <ns:DestinationLocation LocationCode="PEN" />
            <ns:OriginLocation LocationCode="KUL" />
        </ns:FlightSegment>
    </ns:OriginDestinationInformation>
      </ns:FareRQ>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and get this response

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap-env:Header>
      <eb:MessageHeader eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
         <eb:From>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">123123</eb:PartyId>
         </eb:From>
         <eb:To>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">999999</eb:PartyId>
         </eb:To>
         <eb:CPAId>OD</eb:CPAId>
         <eb:ConversationId>UB11</eb:ConversationId>
         <eb:Service eb:type="OTA">FareLLSRQ</eb:Service>
         <eb:Action>FareLLSRS</eb:Action>
         <eb:MessageData>
            <eb:MessageId>2183848454634000151</eb:MessageId>
            <eb:Timestamp>2017-03-17T12:37:43</eb:Timestamp>
            <eb:RefToMessageId>1340037420096900611</eb:RefToMessageId>
         </eb:MessageData>
      </eb:MessageHeader>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
         <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/CERTG!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3296706632225343066!980366!0</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap-env:Header>
   <soap-env:Body>
      <FareRS Version="2.6.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01">
         <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
            <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2017-03-17T07:37:43-05:00">
               <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                  <stl:HostCommand LNIATA="5DE110">FQKULPEN17FEB</stl:HostCommand>
                  <stl:Message code="7012">MDR SUBSET DOES NOT EXIST</stl:Message>
                  <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
               </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
            </stl:Error>
         </stl:ApplicationResults>
      </FareRS>
   </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

I have looked at the Sabre Developer Studio error codes and cannot find any reference to this. The host command for this is FQ and it does not also specify any such error.
I Cannot find anything on googling error code 7012, "MDR SUBSET DOES NOT EXIST"??

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with the latest version since I'm getting a successful response on my end with v2.5.0.

I'd advise you to switch to this version as a workaround and report the same to the helpdesk.

Comment: Thank you. Changing the version works. I have raised with the hep desk as well.